# how to find specific record against array of json objects with complex /nested properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I am trying to use underscorejs to filter out objects from the ajax response that later will be used by my angualr js app. following is the response from server (array of objects).

```
[
    {
      "description": "squash",
      "image": "/categories/8/image",
      "category": "squash",
      "city": "Dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2015-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "dublin squash",
      "users": [
        {
          "image": "/users/2/image",
          "username": "faisal",
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "image": "/users/3/image",
          "username": "zaid",
          "id": 3
        }
      ],
      "address": "Dublin",
      "name": "Squash in dublin",
      "id": 5,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "Tennis event in Dublin",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "Dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2015-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "None",
      "users": [
        {
          "image": "/users/3/image",
          "username": "zaid",
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "username": "admin@dutchit.com",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "image": "/users/2/image",
          "username": "faisal",
          "id": 2
        }
      ],
      "address": "RIchmond road, Dublin 3",
      "name": "Tennis in Dublin",
      "id": 6,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "tennis in karachi",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "Karachi",
      "dateFrom": "2016-03-03 00:00:00",
      "dateTo": "2017-03-03 00:00:00",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "Karachi",
      "name": "Tennis in karachi",
      "id": 7,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "tennis in karachi",
      "image": "/categories/1/image",
      "category": "SPORTS",
      "city": "Karachi",
      "dateFrom": "2016-03-03 00:00:00",
      "dateTo": "2017-03-03 00:00:00",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "Karachi",
      "name": "Tennis in karachi",
      "id": 8,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "tennis in KHIIII",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "Karachi",
      "dateFrom": "2016-05-05 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-05-05 01:01:01",
      "others": "sd",
      "users": [],
      "address": "KHIIII",
      "name": "Tennis in KHIIIII",
      "id": 10,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 123",
      "id": 12,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test12345",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1235",
      "id": 13,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test12346",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1236",
      "id": 14,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test12347",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1237",
      "id": 15,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test12348",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238",
      "id": 16,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123481",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 12381",
      "id": 17,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123482",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 12382",
      "id": 18,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123483",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 12383",
      "id": 19,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123484",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 12384",
      "id": 20,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123485",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 12385",
      "id": 21,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123486",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 12386",
      "id": 22,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123487",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 12387",
      "id": 23,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123488",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 12388",
      "id": 24,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test123489",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 123889",
      "id": 25,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234891",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238891",
      "id": 26,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234892",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238892",
      "id": 27,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234893",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238893",
      "id": 28,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234894",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238894",
      "id": 29,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234895",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238895",
      "id": 30,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234896",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238896",
      "id": 31,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234897",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238897",
      "id": 32,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234898",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238898",
      "id": 33,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234898",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238898",
      "id": 34,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    },
    {
      "description": "test1234899",
      "image": "/categories/2/image",
      "category": "CRICKET",
      "city": "dublin",
      "dateFrom": "2016-12-12 01:01:01",
      "dateTo": "2017-12-12 01:01:01",
      "others": "none",
      "users": [],
      "address": "dublin",
      "name": "test interest 1238899",
      "id": 35,
      "country": "PAKISTAN"
    }
  ];
```

each object in array is an event with some users attached to it. I have two buttons in my angular app one to show all the events and one to show only those events where users property of event matches with current user. So for example current user has id 2. then when he click on my events button only 2 events should be listed.

I am working inside angualr js filter that is linked with ng-repeat let me share both here.

```
iFinder.filter('myevent', function (iFinderFactory) {

    return function (event) {
        console.log("filter in action", iFinderFactory);
        var user = iFinderFactory.getUser();
        console.log("filter user is =", user);
        //console.log("underscore = ", underscore);
        //console.log("evenst:");
        //console.log(event);
        //var eUsers = event.users || [];
        //if (eUsers && eUsers.length > 0) {
        //    console.log(event);
        //    return event;
        //}
        var myEvents = [];
        var gg = _.filter(event, function (e) {
            return _.where(e.users, { id: 3 });
            //return e.users.length > 0;
            //_.each(e.users,function (el, index, list) {
            //    console.log("single e:", el);
            //    if (el.id == user.Id) {
            //        myEvents.push(e);

            //    }
            //    else {

            //    }
            //});
            //window.najams = myEvents;
            //return myEvents;
        });
        event = gg;
        return event;


    };
});
```

Ng-repeat

```
<div class="result" ng-repeat="r in results | myevent">
<h3>{{r.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

using underscore.js fitler method i was able to show all the events who has users registered with them using following code. but cant find events against a user id =3 against users array on event itself. Please help

```
iFinder.filter('myevent', function (iFinderFactory) {

    return function (event) {
        console.log("filter in action", iFinderFactory);
        var user = iFinderFactory.getUser();
        console.log("filter user is =", user);


        var gg = _.filter(event, function (e) {
            return e.users.length > 0;               
        });
        event = gg;
        return event; 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter should be something like this:

```
iFinder.filter('myevent', function () {
    return function (event) {
        var myEvents = [];
        console.log("filter in action", iFinderFactory);
        var user = iFinderFactory.getUser();
        console.log("filter user is =", user);
        //assuming user.id is the id of the user in event.users
        var filtered = _.filter(event, function (e) {
            return _.where(e.users, { id: user.id }).length > 0;
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

I have tried to make a working fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/0zhbrvap/)